# DOM querySelector Difference between 2 code lines

Tags: javascript

Why the second line works while first one doesn't?

```
const elements{
     current: document.querySelector('#current-')
    }
        (elements.current + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
```

Second Line

```
 document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
```

Comment: Because the first is a combination of syntax errors and utter nonsense. JavaScript is a language, with a syntax. You can't rip half a sentence away, glue to somewhere entirely different and still have it make sense.

Comment: Because the first line refers to a DOM element that does not exist, and therefore elements.current becomes undefined.

Comment: Because the first is a combo. Is a combo of nation and syntax errors!

Comment: Because `document.querySelector('#current-') + activePlayer` is not the same as `document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elements.current` will give you an HTMLElement. HTMLElement is an object.
If you concat a string to an object (and vice versa), you will get a string.

So your statement `elements.current + activePlayer` gives you `"[object Object] 123"` (assuming value of your `activePlayer` is `123`

And there is no such property called `textContent` on `String.prototype`

The second one works because you're actually targeting and HTMLElement that has property called textContent on it.